# Xamarin.IOS Duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 when building distribution

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an app that I have compiled for years now, but suddenly I am getting 80-100 duplicate symbols error when building for distribution. Any idea what can have caused this or how to resolve it?

If I turn of LLVM then everything is fine again :-/

```
/var/folders/0h/vq5g4bwx4bl_l6d7w8qfxq6r0000gn/T/tmp121b3ed0.tmp/NDC2010.exe.armv7.o
 duplicate symbol _type_info_98 in:
  /Users/cnordvik/projects/private/myapp/trunk/iPhoneV2/NDC2010/NDC2010/obj/Release/mtouch-      cache/System.armv7.cache.bkurnUkrJNkd4r5Vjq9VHff8nFM=.o
/var/folders/0h/vq5g4bwx4bl_l6d7w8qfxq6r0000gn/T/tmp121b3ed0.tmp/NDC2010.exe.armv7.o
 ld: 632 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug that sneaked into version 6.2.2 (it is [solved](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_6/xamarin.ios_6.2#Xamarin.iOS_6.2.3) in 6.2.3). It only affects some assemblies when using LLVM optimizing compiler.

Your immediate options are either:

- to downgrade to 6.2.1;
- disable LLVM; or
- upgrade to 6.2.3

Comment: Was 6.2.3 released seconds ago? :-) I am sure I checked for update before I posted that question! Thanks!